# Typescript error when I try to use mongoose methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

I have a User interface:

```
import {Document} from "mongoose";

export interface IUser extends Document{
    email: string;
    password: string;
    strategy: string;
    userId: string;
    isValidPassword(password: string): boolean;
}
```

And a schema :

```
import { IUser } from "../interfaces/User";

const userSchema = new Schema({
  strategy: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["local", "facebook", "google"]
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  userId: {
    type: String
  }
});
const User = mongoose.model<IUser>("user", userSchema);
```

Now when I am trying to use:

```
const user :IUser= User.findOne({email});
        if(!user){
            done(null, false)
        }
        user.isValidPassword(password);
```

It says " TS2740: Type 'DocumentQuery<IUser | null, IUser, {}>' is missing the following properties from type 'IUser': email, password, strategy, userId, and 53 more."

If I try to remove 'IUser' from `const user :IUser= User.findOne({email});`. It doesnt let me use `user.isValidPassword(password);`

And I dont want to use `any` type for user.

Answer (score 1):

You should query the `user` document using `await Model.findOne()` statement, see [Model.findOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne).

It will return the `user` with the type `IUser | null`.

Then, you can call the [Instance methods](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) - `user.isValidPassword(password)`.

An working example:

`user.ts`:

```js
import { Document, Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

interface IUser extends Document {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  strategy: string;
  userId: string;
  isValidPassword(password: string): boolean;
}

const userSchema = new Schema({
  strategy: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['local', 'facebook', 'google'],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
  },
  userId: {
    type: String,
  },
});
const User = model<IUser>('user', userSchema);

export { User, IUser };
```

`main.ts`:

```js
import { IUser, User } from './user';

async function main() {
  const email = 'teresa.teng@gmail.com';
  const password = '123';
  const user: IUser | null = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (!user) {
    return;
  }
  user.isValidPassword(password);
}
```

Comment: I am querying the document using the model itself.

In the code 
const user :IUser= User.findOne({email});
        if(!user){
            done(null, false)
        }
        user.isValidPassword(password);

I am getting User from 

`import User from '../models/user'`